# Please explain the scope of for loop indices

Tags: c++

I just want to confirm a suspicion I have about loop indexes. I am using c++. 
I have two for loops in my code. For one I declared my index outside of the loop, i.e

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){ 
. . .
}
cout << i <<endl;
```

And then I have later:

```
for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){
. . .
}
cout << j <<endl;
```

In the first case I see that some random number is outputted. In the second case, I get an error message about -fpermissive or something like that. I just want to confirm that the index goes out of scope whenever the loop ends, because that seems to be what is happening.
I was trying to use the index for something later on, I guess I just have to put a second index in the loop to increment as i or j do, and then I can use this value later. i.e.:

```
 int index = 0;
 for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){
 . . .
 index ++;
 }
cout << index <<endl;
```

Would someone confirm this for me?

Comment: in second sample, scope of `j` is limited to `for loop` only

Comment: if you have an int `n` , and you then say `j<N`, it's not the same as saying `j<n' :)

Comment: I seriously doubt a random value is printed in the first example, unless `n` is random.

Comment: I see you already have the correct answer, I just want to be maybe more clear. Whatever is declared between `{ code here }` it is valid only there. So, in you c++ program, you can easily have something like this: `{ int i; /* do something with i*/}` and after this again `{ int i; /* do something else with i*/}`. `i` can be an iterator for example. Very important, without the curly braces, you can't declare it two times.

Comment: Indeed there was a small problem in my for loop. I fixed it and now I don't get random values after the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example::
http://codepad.org/L5VErMAh

```
int main( void )
{
  int i, n = 10 ;
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++){ 
    // do something useful. . .
  }
  cout << i <<endl;

  return 0 ;
}
```

Output:: `10`
Explanation:: The scope of `i` and `n` is `global` for the `for` loop. So, they don't go invalid or undefined after the execution of `for` loop.

The second example:: http://codepad.org/iqNtQ1Ok

```
int main( void )
{
    int n = 10 ;
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){ 
        // do something useful. . .
    }
    cout << j <<endl;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Output:: `name lookup of 'j' changed for new ISO 'for' scoping`

Explanation:: The scope of `n` is `global` for `for` loop but as the `j` is declared inside the `for` loop, its scope and lifetime is `local` for the `for` loop. That means, the `j` will be and is destroyed after the execution of `for` loop. That's why, the error.

The third example:: I think, you must have got the idea that it is pretty same as the first example.

Now for your doubt, "`In the first case I see that some random number is outputted.`" No, that can't happen unless you are doing something wrong inside the `for` loop. You can post the first case `for` loop code and we can point you out the error.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case,  since j is declared outside the loop, the scope of i is even the outside of the loop. So,

```
cout<<i<<endl;
```

prints the value of `n`. The second case, j is declared in the loop. So the scope of j is only inside the loop; So you get the error.

So the first case itself you can use the value of i at later phases

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    printf("%d\n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

gave me an output of 5.

Answer (score 0):

well this one will just print n

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
//...
}
cout << i <<endl;//prints the value of n
```

and this one J is declared out of scope

```
for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){
. . .
}
cout << j <<endl; //the compiler asks: whats a j?
```

and the last one does the same as the first

```
 int index = 0;
 for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){
 . . .
 index ++;
 }
 cout << index <<endl;//still prints n
```